# How to disable polyline click on overlays?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've dispatched mouse over events on polylines. This event is fired even when I mouse over on an overlay which is on the polyline. How can I avoid it so the overlay actually hides the polyline under it?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably just to set the `Polyline`'s `clickable` property to false when you add the other overlay (which I'm assuming is a custom overlay). Then, the `Polyline` won't respond to mouse events at all, if that is your goal. For that, you simply pass a [PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) object to the `Polyline` constructor, or call the `Polyline.setOptions` function and pass a `PolylineOptions` object, if you want to make the change dynamically after construction.

If you want something with more fine-grained aspects, such as taking full control of the stacking order of overlays, you will want to look into the [MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes). There are seven panes, which are essentially layers where overlays may be added to the map. From **bottom to top**, they stack in this order:

1. `MapPanes.mapPane`
2. `MapPanes.overlayLayer`
3. `MapPanes.overlayShadow`
4. `MapPanes.overlayImage`
5. `MapPanes.floatShadow`
6. `MapPanes.overlayMouseTarget`
7. `MapPanes.floatPane`

Since you are trying to cloak even the mouse events of the `Polyline`, you will probably have to place your other overlay at the top, on the `floatPane`. I do this for some of my [InfoBoxes](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox), which function as rectangle map label boxes. My goal was to put them above *everything else* on the map and they do appear above everything else (the map, markers, overlays, etc.).